# Run Unittests With Authenticated User with Flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-login

I've been trying to run unittests in Python/Flask, but many of the pages on my site involve an authenticated user.  In Django, it's really easy to authenticate a user in the backend (see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#testing-tools).  Is there something similar that I can use in Flask?  I'm currently running the Flask Auth (http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Auth/) authentication system, but I am willing to switch if there is a way to easily test my authenticated pages with another Flask authentication library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Flask integrated unit testing tools](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/)?

You can make post requests with them, so that you can log in log out and act as authenticated users. I don't know if that is sufficient for you, perhaps you need some more advanced stuff, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even see this before. Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I'll take a look now!  Do you know if this works with sqlalchemy (as well as the authentication system that I am currently using), or do I have to switch to Flask's built in authentication system.

Comment: It will certainly work with sqlalchemy, it should work ok with the system you're using.